# tkinter making things next to each other

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to position three Entries next to each other MM, TT and CVC it is for a project. However I can achieve this result, I have tried using sticky and columnspan but from my own understanding these will not work. Any solutions would be helpful

Currently I have: [image]

```
from tkinter import *

Master = Tk(); Master.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

Page = Frame(Master)
Page.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor = "center")

CradnumberEntry = Entry(Page)
CradnumberEntry.insert(0, "Card number")
CradnumberEntry.config(width = int(2 * CradnumberEntry.cget("width")))
CradnumberEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

MMEntry = Entry(Page)
MMEntry.insert(0, "MM")
MMEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "w")
MMEntry.config(width = int(1 / 4 * MMEntry.cget("width")))

YYEntry = Entry(Page)
YYEntry.insert(0, "YY")
YYEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = "w")
YYEntry.config(width = int(1 / 4 * YYEntry.cget("width")))

CVCEntry = Entry(Page)
CVCEntry.insert(0, "CVC")
CVCEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = "w")
CVCEntry.config(width = int(1 / 4 * CVCEntry.cget("width")))
```

Comment: The quickest fix here is to set the column span for your entry to be 3. But a Frame can also solve your problem here.

Answer (score 2):

One very simply solution to this specific layout problem is to conceptualize your GUI as four columns. The first column contains "MM", the next "YY", the third "CVC", and the fourth is to take up all extra space. Then, make sure the "Card Number" field spans all four columns.

To to this requires changing one line of your code, and adding one line:

```
CradnumberEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan=4)
Page.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
```

Another very common solution is to put the widgets that are on the second row into a frame. The "Card Number" entry goes at the top, and this other frame goes below it. Then, you can use `pack` to put the "MM", "YY", and "CVC" entries on the left side of this bottom frame.

```
second_row = Frame(Page)
second_row.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky="ew")
```

This also requires that the parent of the other widgets is this second frame:

```
MMEntry = Entry(second_row)
YYEntry = Entry(second_row)
CVCEntry = Entry(second_row)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is probably to pack all of those entries in a containing `Frame` widget

```
cc_frame = Frame(Page)  # create a container
cc_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

MMEntry = Entry(cc_frame)  # use 'cc_frame' as this widget's parent
MMEntry.insert(0, "MM")
MMEntry.pack(expand=False, fill='none')
MMEntry.config(width = int(1 / 4 * MMEntry.cget("width")))

YYEntry = Entry(cc_frame)  # use 'cc_frame' as this widget's parent
YYEntry.insert(0, "YY")
YYEntry.pack(expand=False, fill='none')
YYEntry.config(width = int(1 / 4 * YYEntry.cget("width")))

CVCEntry = Entry(cc_frame)  # use 'cc_frame' as this widget's parent
CVCEntry.insert(0, "CVC")
CVCEntry.pack(expand=False, fill='none')
CVCEntry.config(width = int(1 / 4 * CVCEntry.cget("width")))
```

BTW, you should avoid variable names with `CapitalLetters` in Python. This syntax is usually reserved for class names (like `Entry` and `Frame` for example). Instead, you should use `snake_case`